# Apply Cauchy-Schwarz to vector?

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces

For $x_i, y_i \in \mathbb{C}$, the C-S inequality gives

$$\left| \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \bar{y}_i \right|^2 \leq \sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|^2 \sum_{k=1}^n |y_k|^2 .$$

Is it true if $x_i, y_i$ are actually vectors, i.e. $x_i, y_i\in \mathbb{R}^n$?

$$\left( \sum_{i=1}^m x_i \cdot y_i \right)^2 \leq \sum_{j=1}^m ||x_j||^2 \sum_{k=1}^m ||y_k||^2 .$$

Is this true? And how to (dis)prove it?

Comment: They have the case for $\mathbb{R}^n$ on wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality
With the proof.

Comment: @Bair That's actually about the first one here.

Comment: They have both. Under special cases they have $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Sorry this is a better link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Rn

Answer (score 1):

It's true. You can show that

$$\sum_{i=1}^m \langle x_i,y_i\rangle$$

is an inner product on $\mathbb C^m$. It's not hard to show that it's bilinear, symmetric, and positive-definite. And as an inner product, it verify the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Comment: Why it's in $C^m$?

Comment: You have m elements of $C, x_1, \cdots,x_m$, you can make a vector of $C^m$ with them.

Comment: I see. I'm not familiar with why scalar product with those properties verifies the inequality. Can you point to a reference?

Comment: I think a clearer viewpoint is that this is actually just the Euclidean inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$. Then we're just indexing $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$ in a somewhat nonstandard way (identifying it with the space of matrices $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$).

Comment: @bl4ck5un : anything with these properties is an inner product. And these properties are the only ones necessary to the standard proof of Cauchy-Schwarz : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Proof